# Angular 5 error for cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: angular

I am trying to create a dynamic form which I will instantiate first with the list of skill names I saved from local storage. But I keep getting this error

"ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined"

What could possible gone wrong in my code?

> I am getting the error from this

```
get userSkillsRating(): FormArray {
        return <FormArray>this.additionalFormGroup.get('userSkillsRating');
}
```

> also this is the method who is using that getter

```
addSkills(skillsName: string): void {
    // console.log("this is the skill name");
    // console.log(skillsName);
    this.userSkillsRating.push(this.buildSkillsRating(skillsName));
}

buildSkillsRating(buildSkillName: string): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
        userSkillName: '',
        userSkillLevel: '',
        userSkillYear: ''
    });
}

populateSkillName(): void {
    this.firstForm = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('firstForm'));
```

> I searched some similar questions but its different from the others because I am using a reactive forms approach for this one. And also the answers from the others doesn't help or address my problems at all.
>
> I instantiated the additionalFormGroup in here:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.loadingJquery();
    this.firstForm = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('firstForm'));
    this.firstForm.userSkills.map(data => this.addUserSkillsRating(data.skillName, data.skillId));

    this.additionalFormGroup = this.fb.group({
        experienceSummary: this.fb.array([ this.buildExperienceSummaryGroup() ], Validators.required),
        proffesionalExperience: this.fb.array([ this.buildProfessionalExperience() ], Validators.required),
        educationSummary: this.fb.array([ this.buildEducationSummary() ], Validators.required),
        userSkillsRating: this.fb.array(this.skillsArray, Validators.required)
    });
    console.log(this.additionalFormGroup);
}
```

Comment: Please only post relevant code. People are more likely to read and answer your question, if it isn't a wall of code.

Comment: Yes the code you posted is irrelevant;(

Comment: Hi @SergeyRudenko, can you explain why is it irrelevant?

Comment: It might be that `additionalFormGroup` is undefined. Where and how do you instantiate it?

Comment: @Geshode. I see that all the code is relevant in order to find the answer: The definition and instantiation of the form (that appears as 'undefined'), the getter where the error happens, and when the getter is used.

Comment: @Winger. It's an old issue, but could you solve it? I can't understand why the form shows and undefined when trying to access with the getter

Answer (score 0):

It occurs when your **additionalFormGroup** variable is undefined. Make sure you initialize **additionalFormGroup** before you call the **userSkillsRating** method.

Comment: Post your **addUserSkillsRating** method